# Spark incorrectly converts a dataset into a dataset of JSON string

Tags: apache-spark

I've came across an odd behavior of `Apache Spark`.
The problem is that I am getting wrong JSON representation of my source dataset when I'm using `toJson()` method.
To explain problem in more detail, imagine I have typed dataset with this fields:

```
SomeObject
(
   adtp 
   date
   deviceType
   ...
)
```

Then I want to map elements of this dataset to JSON using `toJson()` method (for storing objects in Kafka topic).
But Spark converts this objects into their JSON representation incorrectly.

You can see this behaviour on the screenshots:

---

[image]
[image]

---

Before using `toJson()`, the object values were:

```
SomeObject
(
   adtp=1
   date="2019-04-24"
   deviceType="Mobile"
   ...
)
```

After using `toJson()`, the values of the object are:

```
SomeObject
(
   adtp=10
   date="Mobile"
   deviceType=""
   ...
)
```

Can you help me with this sort of problem? I tried to debug spark job but it's not an easy task (I'm not an expert in Scala).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out the cause of the problem. I have some JOINs in my data transformations and then I make my dataset typed (using `as(...)`).
But the problem is that Spark doesn't change the internal schema of the dataset after typing.
And these schemas (one of the source dataset and one of the data model class) may differ. Not only by the presence of columns but also by their order.

So when it comes to conversion of the source dataset to the dataset of JSONs, Spark just takes the schema remaining after the JOINs, and uses it when converting to JSON. And this is the cause of the wrong `toJson()` conversion.

So the solution is quite simple. Just use one of the transformation dataset functions (`map(...)` as an example) to explicitly update your dataset schema. So in my case it looks pretty awful but the most important thing is that it works:

```
.as(Encoders.bean(SomeObject.class))
.map(
      (MapFunction<SomeObject, SomeObject>) obj -> obj,
      Encoders.bean(SomeObject.class)
);
```

There is also a ticket on this problem: [SPARK-17694](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17694).